# How to access an attribute of an img tag in an object within an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of two objects like this:

```
x = {
        word: "Gun",
        pic: "<img id='pic' src='images/stimuli/gun.gif'/>",
    }, {
        word: "Hammer",
        pic: "<img id='pic' src='images/stimuli/hammer.gif'/>",
    }
```

I have to compare the first element of this array via the src attribute to another image tag y:

```
<img id="pic11" height="115" width="90" src="images/stimuli/gun.gif"/>
```

And I tried this comparison and it gives "undefined is not a function":

```
x[0].pic.attr('src') == pic11.src
```

If I log to console like this: `console.log($(x[0].pic).attr('src'))` it works I get `images/stimuli/gun.gif` but I cannot access via the variable x in my script.

In other words, I fail to access the src attribute of the img tag of the object in my array.
How do I do that?

Comment: Did you do `$(x[0].pic).attr('src')` in your script?

Comment: Why do you expect this to work `x[0].pic.attr('src')`? Your `pic` is a string, not a jQuery element. Check the console, there should be a nice error in there with some clue.

Comment: I believe the syntax would work if `x` was an array of objects `x = [{}, {}];`. But the value of x in the example you posted would just be the first object  `x = {}, {}`

Comment: *"If I log to console like this: `console.log($(x[0].pic).attr('src'))` it works"* ... then use that :)

Comment: correct your code and put two [ ] around it to make it an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a jQuery object from the pic attribute and use the .attr() like you were wanting to.

```
var img1 = $(x[0].pic);
var src = img1.attr('src');
```

Comment: The OP seems to know about this already: *"If I log to console like this: `console.log($(x[0].pic).attr('src'))` it works"*

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the tag image tag that you need to access in a jquery wrapper and then try and get the src attribute.

var src = $(x[0].pic).attr('src');

Answer (score 1):

x[0].pic returns a string and not HTML code. So what you need is, convert this String to HTML code and then use $(selector).attr() on it. Below is the changed code:

```
$($.parseHTML(x[0].pic)).attr('src') == pic11.src
```